# Decoding git log complex pretty format

Tags: git, libgit2

i'm trying to porting some `git`-depending stuff to `libgit2` for my Open Source project.
One of the `git` calls is very weird:

```
git log --topo-order --no-color --parents --boundary -z --pretty=format:%m%HX%PX%n%cn<%ce>%n%an<%ae>%n%at%n%s%n%b HEAD --all
```

First of all, i'm interesting in format string.
What means the `X` after `H`? I was unable to find `X` specifier on official git site :/
And the second question - can `libgit2` do this complex formatting, or i should process it myself?

P.S. However, i'm pretty sure it cannot :)

Comment: `X` here seems to be a separator that wraps the parent commit id and separates it from the commit id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `X` is not a format specifier.

The argument to `--pretty=format:` or `--pretty=tformat:` (most users need `tformat`, but this code is using `-z` which adds a NUL character after each commit) contains both *directives* like `%m` and `%H`, and *literal text* that is simply transcribed:

```
$ git log -n 3 --pretty=tformat:hello%x25world
hello%world
hello%world
hello%world
```

Here, the `hello` and `world` strings were simply copied through, while `%x25` was interpreted.  Since it means "print character with hex code 25" which is the percent sign `%`, and `-n 3` told `git log` to stop after logging three commits, we got three copies of `hello%world`.

The literal `X` works because `%m` prints one character that is not `X`, `%H` and `%P` print hashes that do not contain `X`, and `%n` prints a newline—so whatever is reading this output can be sure that each commit begins with the marker character, an `X`, the commit hash, another `X`, and each parent hash with a space between each, then a newline.

The `%s%n%b` sequence is not entirely necessary (one could simply use `%B` instead).  I'm not sure off-hand, though, whether this adjusts the way that "unusually formatted" commits—those that are not a single subject line, followed by a newline, followed by a commit body—come out.  It probably does.

(I know nothing of libgit2.)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation about git command. About libgit2 - looks like, I should try to ask authors of this library directly...